# Where can one find Canon printer icc profiles?

Tags: canon, printing, color-management

I'm using a Linux machine, and i'd like to do soft proofing with GIMP. Although I can choose the paper type in the print dialog, I can't seem to find the actual icc profiles for canon's glossy paper anywhere on the net so that I can import them into GIMP.

So, where can the actual icc profiles for Canon papers on Canon Printers be found?

Comment: Which canon printer and paper?

Comment: Do you mean these? [Canon ICC profiles.](http://www.canon-europe.com/For_Home/Product_Finder/Printers/Inkjet/Professional_Photo_Printers/ICC_Profiles/) If your on Linux, I'd guess the Mac ones should work. There should be profiles for each Canon paper type. Normally these are installed with the drivers, and on windows they can be exported, so if these links don't get what you need, I may be able to provide you with .icc files for the necessary paper types.

Comment: @jrista - i don't own a pro printer, just a regular pixma mg.

Comment: Ah. In the case of the MG line, I don't think Canon has ever produced ICC profiles. I know they had them for the PIXMA Pro9000 and Pro9500 lines, and the new Pro 1/10/100, but beyond that, I'm not sure that Canon has ever created ICC profiles for their other printers. Most third-party paper manufacturers don't create ICC profiles for anything else either. Your pretty much on your own in that case, in which case a SpyderPRINT as in AJ's answer is probably a worthwhile tool.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with ICC profiles for printers is that it depends greatly on the paper being used with the printer.  Common paper types may have existing ICC profiles that you can use, however the best bet is to have one made for you.  You can either use your own calibration unit or send samples out to have an ICC profile built for you.

Personally, on my Pixma Pro-1 I use a [SpyderPRINT](http://spyder.datacolor.com/portfolio-view/spyderprint/) which works pretty well.  I don't remember the specific services I saw for doing it by mail, but some quick searching found [this one](http://www.greatprinterprofiles.com/).  I know there are others available as well, but I ended up going with the SpyderPRINT because I wanted to be able to update it over time and be able to work with different papers without having to wait for sending it in and paying for each paper profile independently.  I also use a Spyder3 for my display calibration, so it was a natural choice for me.  If you don't have screen calibration yet either, Spyder does make a studio option that includes both a Spyder4 and a SpyderPRINT at a slight discount.

One side note, getting a really good profile is a relatively time consuming process.  You have to manually scan several hundred square for the best quality and you need to make sure to carefully position the device for each.  In my opinion, the results are well worth it, but it is another thing to consider when comparing mail away services vs having your own calibration unit.

Comment: Could you maybe link to an ICC printer calibrator and a ICC calibration service? A brief Google search only gives me monitor calibration devices/services.

Comment: @BartArondson - updated with the device I use, a service I found and some additional tips on my experience using the calibrator.

Comment: I've actually been trying to sell my DataColor Spyder Pro package, which includes the screen, print, and camera calibration tools. Darn good deal, if your interested. ;P